# How to pass const arguments to an abstract class parent in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, class, parameters, abstract

i have wrote the following polymorphic code:

```
public abstract class  A  
{  
    readonly int x;  
    A(int i_MyInt)  
    {  
        x = i_MyInt;  
    }  
}  

public abstract class B : A  
{  
    //holds few integers and some methods      
}  


// concrete  object class  
public class C : B   
{  
   // holds some variables and mathods  
    C(int MyInt)  
    {   
      // here i would like to initialize A's x  
    }  
}
```

how can i initialize  A's x from C
i tried passing parameters to A's C'tor - but didn't work..

Please Help,
Thanks in advance
Amitos80

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add a constructor to B that takes an integer and passes it to A's constructor. You can then call this constructor from C.

```
public abstract class B : A
{  
    public B(int myInt) : base(myInt)
    {
        // other initialization here...
    }  
}  

public class C : B
{
    // holds some variables and mathods  
    public C(int myInt) : base(myInt)
    {
        // other initialization here...
    }
}
```

A's constructor must also not be private.

Comment: +1 you would need this anyway, as there is no default constructor for class A.

Comment: Alternatively you can also make A's x protected or public and then set it from C's constructor.